# How to mount a block device with no partition table in Windows

Tags: windows, virtualization, filesystems

The filesystem starts from sector 0. I have an encrypted container on the host and want to pass decrypted media to the windows guest as a single physical device that is intended to be mounted on guest. I don't want to use filesharing service between host and guest, it is slow and introduce unneeded overhead compared to simple block device sharing.

Comment: You don't mention which virtualization software you're using.

Comment: VMware Player, but this is not important, the question is about the windows guest ability to mount disks with raw filesystem without partition table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy userspace solution is to mount a drive using ImDisk, to mount a raw drive use the path `\\.\PhysicalDriveN` where N is the hard drive number in windows.